# Provider not recognized from react-redux - NextJS RTK Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

I am trying to integrate Redux RTK to my Next JS 13.4 app. I follow some tutorials to do that, but I get the same error again and again in my provider.ts file

```
'use client'
import { store } from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

export function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

The error is :
`'Provider' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Provider'?ts(2749)`

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled react-redux and other packages, I already tried to change my eslintrc.json, but nothing changes. The Provider import from react-redux is not used in the return statement, it still appears grey tint in the import statement.

The rest of the Redux implementation is here:

store.ts

```
'use client'
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from './features/auth-slice';

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authReducer,
    },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

auth-slice.ts

```
'use client'

import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export interface User {
    isAuth: boolean;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    isModerator: boolean;
}

export interface AuthState {
    user: User | null;
}

const initialState: AuthState = {
    user: null,
};

export const auth = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        registerUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<Partial<User>>) => {
            const { id, name } = action.payload;
            state.user = {
                isAuth: true,
                id: id || '',
                name: name || '',
                isModerator: true,
            };
        },
        changeName: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
            if (state.user) {
                state.user.name = action.payload;
            }
        },
    },
});

export const { registerUser, changeName } = auth.actions;

export default auth.reducer;
```

And the final implementation in my layout.tsx at the root of my app folder

```
import { Providers } from '@/redux/provider';
import './globals.css';

export const metadata = {
    title: 'Coworking Pro',
    description: 'Trouve ton coworking gratuit',
};

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
    return (
        <html lang='fr'>
            <body className='w-screen overflow-x-hidden'>
                <Providers>{children}</Providers>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

There is no error in this last file.

Thank you for your help

I reinstall all the packages, change some config files (eslint). I copy-pasted some tutorials that are actually working. But not for me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error too, I just change my file name from ts to tsx, forget typescript actually takes to account if there is jsx or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).